# Initiate windows feature update after snoozing

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1709

Windows informed me a day ago that the Fall Creators Update was ready to install. It wasn't the best time, so I snoozed the alert for 3 days. Now is a good time but it hasn't been 3 days, so I can't find anything to initiate the feature update.

If I look in update history, it shows the feature update and says "requires a restart to finish installing". But clicking that just gives a tooltip with a little more info about the update. Checking for updates tells me there are no updates available. Doing a regular PC restart just does a normal restart and doesn't initiate the update.

Is there anything I can do to kick off the feature update? Or do I have to wait until the snooze expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the period of the 3 days you may start the update by :

Go to the
[Microsoft software download website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
and click on `Update now`.
It might be safer to use Internet Explorer or perhaps Edge for this.

If that didn't work, or if the 3 days have elapsed and the update hasn't
arrived, then there is a glitch with Windows Update.

To correct the problem, do the following steps in order until one works,
rebooting after each step :

- From the Start menu, enter Troubleshooting and use
  "Fix problems with Windows Update"
- A manual procedure which is probably very similar to the above
  is to
  [Reset Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components)
  so as to restart from scratch.
- The more complicated method is to download from the
  [Microsoft software download website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
  the Media Creation Tool and with it to download the full Windows release,
  and launch it to upgrade.

Unfortunately, you will most likely need to re-download the entire update.
I would suggest backing fully your files before starting with such
a consequential update.